# Is it possible to increment an SSI variable by 1?

Tags: apache, ssi

For example want to increment an integer by one each time an #if is successfully met:

```
<!--#set var="DISPLAY_COUNT" value="0" -->

<!--#if expr="${DATE_UNIX} > 1429097966 && ${DATE_UNIX} < 1439097966" -->
    <!--#set var="DISPLAY_COUNT" value="$DISPLAY_COUNT++" -->
    <p>You can see me, wooo</p>
<!--#endif-->

<p><!--#echo var="DISPLAY_COUNT" --> include(s) are visible</p>
```

Ideally I'd want the DISPLAY_COUNT to then display 1 if the above #if statement is met.

Is this even possible? I know, its probably not the best way to do this kind of thing, but SSI are really the best of a bad situation here.

Answer (score 0):

No, **no math is possible** in SSI variable values, because they are treated **as string**.

The only way I found is *using external script*, here is some example:
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/cgi/ch06_02.htm#ch06-13635

Apache docs for executing commands:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html#exec

P.S. Only appliable for Apache SSI (not nginx etc.)